# What i can use as progress bar and count iterations ? Python

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, counting

Example i was try use progress.bar, alive_progress.

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar
with alive_bar(100) as bar:
    for i in range(100):
        for i in combinations_with_replacement(['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b'], 8):
            b = (''.join(i))
            bar()
```

and i hv many annoing problems or it slow down script , not work as expecter with print ( print simple print over this bar or its creates new bar after any print.

If i run it with no bar/counting it finish at ~0.001 second .

as exmaple i was try with tqdm

```
    from itertools import *
    from tqdm import trange
    for i in trange(100):
        for i in combinations_with_replacement(['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b'], 8):
            b = (''.join(i))
```

if i dissble it it finish  less than second , if i use it , it expect time is 3 m , how to this this and not slowdown script?

UPD : if belive info what find at goodle that progress bars and counters for pyhon is not usable , only if you dont care bout 1000% slowdown script.

but some how progress bars is used at any brutforce scripts ,  generators etc...
i dont undestand .

```
from itertools import *
from collections import Counter
from tqdm import *
#for i in tqdm(Iterable):
limit = product(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'], repeat = 8)
for i in trange(100):
    for j in limit:
        b = (''.join(j))
        if b in ['bbbbbbbb','11111111','aaaaaaaa','00001111']:
            print (b)
```

its static before script is and so to not work. ( stay at 0% all runing and go instantly to 100% when it end)

You can commnent logic "if b in and print" notting no change .

Comment: You can use the `tqdm` package

Comment: I try all , they all hv problem at python 3.8 , they all slowdown script , with no progerss bares script finish work at 0.001 second , with bares, its slowdown 5 - 10 second!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the script is slowing down is that the `combinations_with_replacement()` function is being called for each progress bar update.
I calculated the value outside the loop and the output was instant.
The rate of execution went from 2 s/it (0.5 it/s) -> 60 it/s

```py
from itertools import *
from tqdm import trange
limit = combinations_with_replacement(['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b'], 8)
for i in trange(100):
    for j in limit:
        b = (''.join(j))
```

Comment: its work , but progress bar have only 2 stages , 0 and 100. So it now work only how timeit

Comment: It is not that the progress bar has only 2 stages, but that it computes very fast, so goes from 0 to 100 instantly..

Comment: I update post , try what i put ( it the same but make more calculations by more repitions from itertools.product end you will see it is static  before script is end)

Comment: I am not understanding your question... Do you need it to go slower? You can use `time.sleep()` for that, and you are not making more calculations with a single if statement..

Comment: What you dont understand ? I need progress bar to see progress not see start and and time , for this i can use timeit , how i say your sulution not work! try  how at example at fisrt post and you see there is no progress  - 0 at script start and instantly 100% when it and , but no progress like 1 2 3 4 % , no mater how long it runing